# How to except ValueError in another module in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

1st file:

```
try:

    # some code

except ValueError, Argument:

    print Argument
```

2nd file:

```
company = "App"

if company is "Apple":

    # code

elif company is "Samsung":

    # code

else:

    raise ValueError("Invalid compnay name")
```

My requirement is to raise error in a file and except it in another file.

I tried above code, but its not accepting the ValueError raised.

Comment: Please provide a complete, runnable example that demonstrates the issue. Right now it's unclear how the two files relate to each other.

Comment: I guess you mean module. You should provide a better example anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Top level code in a module it is executed when loaded for the first time, which is in general not what you want. You need to have a function that you are able to call from a different module. And this function call is easily wrapped.

For instance, let's say you have a module1 with the following code

```
# module1.py

def do_something():
    # blabla
    raise ValueError
```

and then in your module2, you can import the module1 and use `do_something`, wrapping it in a try-except block

```
# module2

import module1

try:
    module1.do_something()

except ValueError:
    print "bam! exception!"
```

**EDIT**

Side note: comparing strings by identity is wrong. It works because of object caching... until it doesnt. You want to compare that the string has an explicit value. Example:

```
if company == "Apple":
    # blabla
```

The same goes for numbers.

This works

```
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 4
>>> a is b
True
```

But this doesn't, because numbers are not always cached

```
>>> a = 99999999
>>> b = 99999999
>>> a is b
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor code in your 2nd file to a function:

```
def checkCompany(company):
    if company == "Apple":  #DON'T use "is" to check the equality of strings
        pass
    elif company == "Samsung":
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid compnay name")
```

then import & call it from your 1st file:

```
import your_second_file
try:
    name='apppple'  #an invalid company name
    your_second_file.checkCompany(name)
except ValueError, e:
    print e
```